# Unable to call methods from imported jars if the package name is different

Tags: java, jar

I have a method **M1** in Class **C1** under the package **P1** and which is under Java project called **JP1**. I am able to successfully exported jar file without any issues.

After adding the jar file to classpath in another project, I tried to call the method M1 under the package P2 under the Java project called JP2, but for some reason, I am not able to find the method "M1" since the package name P1 and P2 are different, **If I maintain the P2 package name as P1 then i am able to call M1 method**.

1. How to call the method if package names are different?

Note: I exported the jar file in Eclipse without any issues.

Comment: Is the class C1 public ?

Comment: Have you tried creating the object of class C1 with full qualified name like P1.C1 = new P1.C1(); and then P1.C1.M1 in your P2 class?

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary, Yes Class C1 is public only.

Comment: @Haswan if class and function both are public you should be able to call them from any package. could you put your class and method declaration ?

Answer (score 0):

That means either the method, or the class the method is in (or if that class is in another class, that class, all the way until you get to a top-level class; one that is the top outer thing inside its own source file) is not marked `public`. Mark them as such; you have explicitly told java you do not wish for the construct to be visible outside of the package.

So, you have this:

```java
class MyClass {
    public void foo() {}
}
```

or this:

```java
public class MyClass {
    void foo() {}
}
```

(or combined; both the class and the method aren't public). You need this:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public void foo() {}
}
```